# I'm trying to filter posts by calculating their relevance score but all relevance score turns out to be 0 (Node.js backend and PostgreSQL DB)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend

I'm using Node.js and express server and PostgreSQL for my backend for a journalism website. I'm trying to use this route to filter posts by calculating their relevance score:

```
app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
    const categories = req.query.categories
        ? req.query.categories.split(",")
        : [];
    const tags = req.query.tags ? req.query.tags.split(",") : [];
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 3;
    const offset = (page - 1) * limit;

    let sqlQuery = `
        SELECT p.*, u.display_name,
            ARRAY(
                SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT category_id FROM post_categories WHERE post_id = p.id
                )
            ) AS categories,
            ARRAY(
                SELECT name FROM tags WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = p.id
                )
            ) AS tags,`;

    let params = [];
    let paramCounter = 1;

    if (categories.length > 0 || tags.length > 0) {
        sqlQuery += `COALESCE((SELECT SUM(score) FROM (`;

        if (categories.length > 0) {
            sqlQuery += `SELECT 3 AS score FROM post_categories pc JOIN categories c ON pc.category_id = c.id WHERE pc.post_id = p.id AND c.name = ANY($${paramCounter}::text[]) `;
            params.push(categories);
            paramCounter++;
        }

        if (tags.length > 0) {
            if (categories.length > 0) {
                sqlQuery += `UNION ALL `;
            }
            sqlQuery += `SELECT 1.5 AS score FROM post_tags pt JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.id WHERE pt.post_id = p.id AND t.name = ANY($${paramCounter}::text[]) `;
            params.push(tags);
            paramCounter++;
        }

        sqlQuery += `) AS subquery), 0) AS relevance_score `;
    } else {
        sqlQuery += `0 AS relevance_score `;
    }

    sqlQuery += `
        FROM posts p
        JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
        GROUP BY p.id, u.display_name
        ORDER BY relevance_score DESC NULLS LAST, p.date DESC
        LIMIT $${paramCounter} OFFSET $${paramCounter + 1}`;

    params.push(limit, offset);

    try {
        const result = await db.query(sqlQuery, params);
        res.json(result.rows);
        console.log(result.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error executing query", err.stack);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error fetching posts." });
    }
});
```

The req's params will include categories and/or tags or neither. If a post's category match any of the selected categories, it will gain 3 points.(Each post only have 1 category) Each tag of a post that match any of the selected tags will add 1.5 point to the post(Each post can have 1-2 tags). However, when I test it, every post's relevance score is 0.

Please give me some ideas where does this problem comes from or help me fix it. It will be a life-saver!!!